# Forge BIM 360 Photos

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is there an endpoint available in Forge to access BIM360 **albums** and **photos**? I refer specifically to albums and photos contained in the **Photos** tab on the **Document Management** module. I am trying to download some of these photos into a local drive, depending on their attributes values.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no API to access BIM 360 Photos.